# Remove punctuation mark after the preg split

Tags: php

I am using this code to split my content after the first punctuation mark, retrieving the fist sentence.

```
$content = preg_split('/(?<=[!?.])./', $content);
```

How can I remove that remaining punctuation mark at the end of the splitted sentence?

Comment: Provide example **Input and Output**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$content = "Hello, world! What's new today? Everything's OK.";
$arr = preg_split('/[!?.] ?/', $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($arr);
```

This splits on punctuation mark `!?.` followed by an optionnal space.  The captured strings don't contain leading space.

The difference with yours is that I don't catch the punctuation.

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello, world
    [1] => What's new today
    [2] => Everything's OK
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run after this

```
$content = ltrim($content, '.');
```

or

```
$content = str_replace('.', '', $content);
```

Comment: no, if you use ltrim its remove only the dot in the end of the sentence, str_replace replace every occurrence of dot

Comment: I need something to remove all punctuation

Comment: ok look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762546/php-the-best-way-to-remove-punctuation-marks-symbols-diacritics-special-char or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751308/remove-the-punctuation-mark-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$content = substr($content, 0, -1);
```

This will remove the last character from `$content`.

Comment: That does not seem to work, it substracts all my sentence:) tried it before myself

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = preg_split('/[!?.]/', $content, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

try dis code!

```
$test   =   'Ho! My! God!';
    $temp   =   split('!',trim($test,'!'));
    echo "=".__LINE__."=><pre>";print_r($temp);echo "</pre>";
    Array
(
    [0] => Ho
    [1] =>  My
    [2] =>  God
)
```